# DSolve returning an InverseFunction Inactive[Integrate] ProductLog as a solution

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations, inverse-function

When using DSolve I get the below output, a1, b, and c1 are real and positive.

```
P1[z] -> InverseFunction[Inactive[Integrate][1/(K[1] (1 + ProductLog[-((b (E^(-(C[1]/a1) + (b K[1])/a1))^(a1/(a1 - c1)))/(a1 - c1))])), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][a1 z - c1 z + C[2]]
```

`K[1]` and `C[2]` were generated by DSolve. How would I go about simplifying or solving this function for `P1[z]`?

Comment: You might try solving for `z[P1]` instead.  In any case, please provide more information, including the code that you used to obtain the answer you site and an explanation of how you intend to use `P1[z]`.

Comment: The code used is
DSolve[{P1'[z] == a1*P1[z] - b*P1[z]*P2[z] - c1*P1[z], 
  P2'[z] == b*P2[z] - c2*P2[z]*P1[z]}, {P1[z], P2[z]}, z]

P1 is the power that I am concerned with as it travels along the z direction. Some of the power is lost to P2 and the amount of loss increases depending on P1. I want to be able to graph P1 with respect to z.

Comment: Integrate cannot evaluate the integral, so it is represented unevaluated.  To proceed, you need to solve the problem numerically using `NDSolve`.  This in turn requires providing numerical values for all the constants and for initial conditions.

Comment: For instance, `NDSolveValue[{P1'[z] == a1*P1[z] - b P1[z]*P2[z] - c1*P1[z], P2'[z] == b P2[z] - c2*P2[z]*P1[z], P1[0] == 1, P2[0] == 1} /. {a1 -> 1, b -> 1, c1 -> 1, c2 -> 1}, {P1[z], P2[z]}, {z, 0, 2}] // Flatten; 
Plot[%, {z, 0, 2}]`